# Performance boost with DNS caching?

Tags: performance, caching, ubuntu, dns

**IN SHORT:**

How would one create a local DNS cache on a linux system (ubuntu) so that common queries can run faster, and is it then possible to purge it?

The cache should be populated upon first-queries, not created by hand.

**BACKGROUND:**

There's a web server up in the cloud which makes connections to itself since the database is currently on the same (virtual)machine. To make it easier for future expansion where the database will be on another server, I've simply pointed the webserver at an address like database.example.com and set the DNS record to 127.0.0.1. The plan is that I can then simply change the DNS record once everything's migrated over. This might seem overkill with just web and database, but there will be other types of servers too (redis, node.js, etc.)

The problem is that when I use the hostname version, it is going very slow (5-10 seconds for session_start). When I use the IP address (i.e. 127.0.0.1), it is very fast (a couple milliseconds).

It seems clear to me that the problem is in DNS, and I believe local caching is a fine solution since it will allow me to manage it all in one place, rather than having to step through the different parts of the system and change configuration.

Comment: Is this a Windows server? If so, you might find that disabling IPv6 will make it fast - there's an issue with post-IPv6 versions of Windows (Server 2008 onwards I think) that it will always attempt to do an IPv6 lookup first - this normally manifests as a 5-10 second delay, hence why I'm suggesting it :)

Comment: linux/ubuntu - edited above to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Install dnsmasq

```
  apt-get install dnsmasq
```

Lock it down to only localhost add the following to /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

start your service and verify that it is running

```
service dnsmasq start
dig www.google.com @127.0.0.1
```

Edit /etc/resolv.conf add the following as your first line

```
  nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

And remove options rotate if present.

Note you may have some scripts automatically rewriting / changing /etc/resolv.conf it which case you'll have to change those as well (ie dhclient or /etc/network/interfaces)